# "Is" or "Are" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct - "Is" or "Are" in this sentence?

"Additionally, early booking discounts on full-day childcare **is/are** offered."

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you are talking about discounts that is a plural, it will be 'are'.

If you change the word 'discounts' to 'discount', 'are' will be replaced by 'is'.